# Why are the converted clicks totals different between Locations and Keywords in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goals

Here is my case:

- Under "Campaign → Keywords", the total converted clicks (search + display network) is 3.
- Under "Settings → Locations", the total converted clicks is 2.

Why are the two values different? Does Google Analytics sometimes fail to recognize countries?